# Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null' context

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

why I get this ts error:

```
Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'null'.
```

Context.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

type ForgotPasswordProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export type Email = {
  email: string | null;
  setEmail: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> | null;
}

export const ForgotPasswordContext = createContext<Email | null>(null);

export const ForgotPasswordContextProvider = ({
  children
}: ForgotPasswordProviderProps) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  return <ForgotPasswordContext.Provider value={{email, setEmail}}>{children}</ForgotPasswordContext.Provider>
}
```

ForgotPassword.tsx

```
  const handleChangeEmail = (e: string) => (emailContext && emailContext.setEmail('asas');
```

this error comes on line: **emailContext.setEmail**

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your context defines this type:

```
export type Email = {
  email: string | null;
  setEmail: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> | null;
}
```

Which says that the `setEmail` property could be a state setter function or it could be `null`.

Which means when you execute this:

```
emailContext && emailContext.setEmail('asas')
```

Then `emailContext.setEmail` might be `null`.

To fix it you need to verify that the property has a value before you use it. You can use the optional chaining operator `?.` to safely drill in here:

```
emailContext?.setEmail?.('asas')
```